# How to Apply a Mathematical Equation on a Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have uploaded a table in GEE with height and diameter columns.Now I want to write a function that would apply an equation to each feature. I am unable to use a simple equation as I might have done in excel. The '.expression ' in GEE works only on images not on feature collection. Please suggest a simple method to do it.

Here is the link to my fusion table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1tuVLITArmX663I8wGZ3l6h-hAN9_q6wO_5papUwi

This is the equation I want to implement :  ln(AGB)=5.349+0.96*ln(D^2H)

where D is for DBH (m) and H is for height (m)

Comment: use fusion tables to do the work https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/178196?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a computed property for a feature collection, you can map a function over it as explained here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collection_mapping.

In your case, this would be the code:

```js
/***
 * Computes ln(AGB)=5.349+0.96*ln(D^2H)
 */
function computeLnAGB(feature) {
  var d = ee.Number(feature.get('DBH (m)'));
  var h = ee.Number(feature.get('Height (m)'));

  return feature.set({ v: d.pow(h.multiply(2)).log().multiply(0.96).add(5.349) });
}

var features = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tuVLITArmX663I8wGZ3l6h-hAN9_q6wO_5papUwi');

// generate a new property for all features
features = features.map(computeLnAGB);

// show new property values
print(features.aggregate_array('v'));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d10435d22e4b0d53a33439b17475ea5c